# Does a Warforged receive all the benefits of a long rest while wearing armor?

Tags: dnd-5e, racial-traits, armor, rests, warforged

In *Eberron: Rising From The Last War* (p. 36), the [Warforged's Integrated Protection trait](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/warforged#WarforgedTraits) states that you can take a rest while donning or doffing armor. The Sentry's Rest trait also states that you appear inert, which I and my group have interpreted as being able to sit or stand anywhere in a kind of powered-down mode.

Using the [optional resting rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/xgte/dungeon-masters-tools#SleepinginArmor) from *Xanathar's Guide to Everything* (p. 77-78), does a Warforged have to take off their armor to receive full hit dice and remove exhaustion during a long rest?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, Warforged can benefit from a long rest by RAW.

Xanathar’s Guide to Everything, pg 78 says:

"When you finish  a long rest in which you slept in medium or heavy armor ..."

Eberron: Rising From the Last War pg 36 details Warforged racial traits, among them "You do not need to sleep"

So you're fine.  Even if you are using the optional rules from Xanathar’s, they only apply to characters who sleep.  And Warforged don't.  (Nor do Elves, so an Elf can also just chill in heavy or medium Armor for a long rest without penalty as well)